# underscore template exception

Tags: underscore.js

I have this template:

```
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><%= created =%></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-warning btn-small"><i class="icon-edit icon-white"></i> Edit</a></td>
</tr>
```

When I try to process it via:

```
var row = _.template(user_template, {created: "aa"});
```

It throws this exception:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
```

When I remove `<%= created =%>` it works correctly returning `<tr><td>...</tr>`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<%= created =%>` should be changed to `<%= created %>`

Answer (score 2):

It is the trailing =%>

Should be just %>

Like this <%= created %>